# Reading Lines Asynchronously in Haskell

Tags: haskell, asynchronous

I am trying to read lines without blocking using Async. I have figured out how to read one line, but I don't know the correct approach to make this continuous. Ideally I would like to have a generator that I could read the next line without blocking the main loop. How could I go about this?

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

-- New async reader
main :: IO ()
main = do
  getl <- async getLine
  mainLoop getl

-- Read stdin and echo forever
mainLoop :: Async String -> IO ()
mainLoop getl = do
  tryRead getl >>= tryPrint
  threadDelay $ 1000 * 1000
  mainLoop getl

-- Try to read stdin without blocking
tryRead :: Async String -> IO (Maybe String)
tryRead recvr = do
  res <- poll recvr
  case res of
    Nothing -> return Nothing
    Just (Right a) -> return $ Just a
    Just (Left e) -> error $ show e

-- Try to print string
tryPrint :: Maybe String -> IO ()
tryPrint (Just str) = print str
tryPrint Nothing = return ()
```

Output. What I assume is happening is that the Async getline is evaluated the first time, and then that value is returned every subsequent time the Async is polled.

```
hell
"hell"
"hell"
"hell"
"hell"
"hell"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `async` itself don't give you all the communication capabilities you need. It can handle starting the thread, and cleaning it up, but you'll need a channel to actually get the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution using channel streams from unagi-chan.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent hiding (newChan, writeChan)
import Control.Concurrent.Chan.Unagi.NoBlocking

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (inchan, outchan) <- newChan
  _ <- forkIO $ getStdin inchan
  [stream] <- streamChan 1 outchan
  mainLoop stream

mainLoop :: Stream String -> IO ()
mainLoop stream = do
  (str, stream') <- getNext stream
  forM_ str print
  threadDelay 1000
  mainLoop stream'

getStdin :: InChan String -> IO ()
getStdin chan = forever $ getLine >>= writeChan chan

getNext :: Stream String -> IO (Maybe String, Stream String)
getNext stream = do
  next <- tryReadNext stream
  case next of
    Next str stream' -> return (Just str, stream')
    Pending -> return (Nothing, stream)
```

Comment: My understanding is that it's usually considered better to use a bounded channel for real applications. That way, you don't accept more work than you can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked something together which seems to work, although its a little ugly.
tryRead now returns the next async to poll, which is either the old async event or a new one.
I would like to remove the necessity to pass the async event around, but I guess this will do for now.

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

-- New async reader
main :: IO ()
main = mainLoop Nothing

-- Read stdin and echo forever
mainLoop :: Maybe (Async String) -> IO ()
mainLoop getl = do
  (res, getl') <- tryRead getl
  tryPrint res
  threadDelay 1000
  mainLoop (Just getl')

-- Try to read stdin without blocking
tryRead :: Maybe (Async String) -> IO (Maybe String, Async String)
tryRead Nothing = do
  recvr <- async getLine
  return (Nothing, recvr)
tryRead (Just recvr) = do
  res <- poll recvr
  case res of
    Nothing -> return (Nothing, recvr)
    Just (Right a) -> do recvr' <- async getLine
                         return (Just a, recvr')
    Just (Left e) -> error $ show e

-- Try to print string
tryPrint :: Maybe String -> IO ()
tryPrint (Just str) = print str
tryPrint Nothing = return ()
```

Comment: Forking a new thread for every line sounds horribly inefficient.

Comment: I bet it is, but its good enough for my purposes at the moment. I would like a better solution.

Comment: Use a channel! Search Hackage for bounded concurrent channels; `unagi-chan` is popular, but `base` has some options as well. There's absolutely no rule that an `Async` can only yield information in its final return value, and in many applications they write to channels, modify `MVar`s, etc.

Comment: unagi-chan looks usable. I took a look at standard channels previously but the operations seemed blocking.